# Is the clojure.test.check.random namespace meant to be used externally?

Tags: random, clojure, test.check

The Clojure [`test.check`](https://github.com/clojure/test.check/tree/test.check-0.9.0) library includes an immutable version of the functionality provided by the Java [`SplittableRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SplittableRandom.html) class, as described by Gary Fredericks in his ["Purely Random"](https://youtu.be/u0t-6lUvXHo) talk. However, the [API docs](http://clojure.github.io/test.check/) for `test.check` exclude the `clojure.test.check.random` namespace in which this functionality is implemented. Is this namespace meant to be used directly from code outside of `test.check`, or should it be treated as an implementation detail and not used in that way?

Comment: Not really a question for Stack Overflow, is it? Ask the maintainers?

Comment: @glts Where should this question be asked, exactly?

Comment: @glts Also, this question doesn't seem very different from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33845364/5044950) that I've asked in the past; no one said that one was off-topic, so I'm curious why this one would be.

Comment: what kind of use are you asking about? using the RNG for unrelated things, or using it to write lower-level code that interacts with the rest of test.check?

Comment: @gfredericks Using it for unrelated things. It seems like the best way to deal with random number generation functionally in Clojure as far as I can tell.

Comment: I think that's a fine way to use it; I think the best situation would be for it to be split into a separate contrib library, but that hasn't happened yet.

Comment: @gfredericks I agree, but I was hesitant to suggest because I know that you guys are generally pretty busy. Would I be able to do anything to help in moving it into its own library? I've signed the Clojure CA, if that means anything.

Comment: You can propose it on the clojure-dev list, I think they'd be receptive. I think the unclear part would be what the scope of the library should be; e.g., should it have functions with global state like `clojure.core/rand`? Should it have functions that provide interesting distributions, or just 64 bit ints? Etc.

Comment: @gfredericks I've started a [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure-dev/4GykG7Ia4Tc) on the clojure-dev Google group, as you suggested.